# Running Macro on Close of Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I did not see any questions of this sort, so I thought I'd ask. I want users to update a table where they add their name to handling an issue. On the close of the table (or workbook), I'd like a macro to run to change the status of the issue with assignees to "In Process".

So, for example,

```
1b235d Jose "In Process"
1dhjfj      "New"
```

Comment: There are no events for opening or closing tables in VBA.

Comment: You could use the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event. From your question: `On the close of the table (or workbook),`

Comment: Users should not interact directly with tables and queries, only forms and reports. Forms and reports have Open and Close events.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to 'wrap' your table in a form.  Then you can respond to the Close event and do whatever logic you need.

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
   'put your code here to change the status
End Sub
```

How would you do this?  Here are some steps to get you started:

1. Create a form and set the Default View to Datasheet
2. Set the Record Source to your table
3. Create the Event as shown above